# Why is infinite data required to verify statistical independence

Tags: normal-distribution, independence, central-limit-theorem, independent-component-analysis

I've been reading about Independent Component Analysis and the FastICA algorithm. The wiki page for FastICA states:

> FastICA is an efficient and popular algorithm for independent
>   component analysis invented by Aapo Hyvärinen at Helsinki University
>   of Technology.[1][2] Like most ICA algorithms, FastICA seeks an
>   orthogonal rotation of prewhitened data, through a fixed-point
>   iteration scheme, that maximizes a measure of non-Gaussianity of the
>   rotated components. **Non-gaussianity serves as a proxy for statistical
>   independence, which is a very strong condition and requires infinite
>   data to verify.**

I understand that non-gaussianity can serve as a proxy for independence due to the central limit theorem, but why is it that independence itself requires infinite data to verify?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Independence, like many other concepts in statistics, is a feature of a population rather than a sample. You can't conclude much with certainty about a population from only a finite random sample, since you could always be arbitrarily unlucky in your choice of sample.

Comment: Ah, didn't realize the answer was that simple. Great, thanks.

Comment: Yes, but by that reasoning *everything* requires "infinite data." (except when sampling from finite populations).  Thus, either the quotation is a meaningless triviality or else something else was meant.

Comment: @whuber I tend towards thinking "meaningless triviality", but it's possible that the author meant something else.